# How can I redirect only main file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this site that has the following structure

```
site
    |-- .htaccess
    |-- index.php
    |-- other files and directories
```

`index.php` file is used for every redirect. How can I use modify the `.htaccess` to only redirect to `mydomain.com/desiredLink` only when someone wants to access `mydomain.com` and not when anyone used `mydomain.com/otherlink` or `mydomain.com/index.php?stuff`?

current .htaccess content is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect root URL
RewriteRule ^/?$ /desiredLink [L,R]

# other than root URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```